# avoid System Repair

Tags: windows-vista, usb, boot

A coworker had an electrical hit and lost usage of usb and ps2 on her computer. I added in a pci to usb card to get it back to "usable"...The usb ports seem to be inactive until windows boots, have no use of keyboard to get into the bios or control anything before login screen.

The computer was improperly shutdown and on startup it comes up with "Launch System Repair"(default) or start normally. I can't switch it to start normally because usb from the pci card isn't active yet. Runs through a check and then ask me if I want to use system restore, but still, no keyboard.

If I pull the hard drive into another computer, is there a file I can modify to tell it not to perform the system check? There has to be a file somewhere that has a flag set to do this, I just have no idea what or where to look.

Comment: This is affecting the motherboard USB ports (back ports)? or also affecting the internal USB connector (that is connected to the front port)? - Just checking if there may still be some chance a USB port is still alive after the electrical hit.

Comment: both front and rear ports are out of commission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that's annoying... maybe try this:

Move the drive to the working PC, as primary, and boot it into safe mode (F8 as soon as BIOS screen passes).  (If that doesnt work try recovery console off the win7 disc.)

Then go into elevated command prompt and type:

bcdedit /set {default} bootstatuspolicy ignoreallfailures

Install back into the defunct PC and try again.

Also I hope that windows is set to autologin.  Sometimes I've seen where PCI / USB devices won't install until after login.  If that happens you should just remote desktop into the PC and allow it to install the new pci device.

Comment: Thanks for actually reading the question unlike the other two...  I had tried using the bcdedit before, but forgot about the elevated permission... I have it up and running now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once you are booted into safe mode, open up a run window. Run `msconfig`.

[image: msconfig]

Once this window has opened, you will be able to adjust your boot options, and tell the system to do a normal boot next time it runs.

Comment: I can't get into safe mode, keyboard doesn't work until sometime around the login screen comes up.  what is the file that this configuration is stored to so i can manually modify it from another computer?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Try this]
Uncheck the "Time to display recovery option..."
Does that help?

Comment: Cannot get into windows to make that edit...